# Sort objects of a list (by date) and removing the oldest, then reorder them again

Tags: c#

I have objects that I assigned the entry dates to them so they are sort by date and the oldest in the list have to be filled with red color,
what I want to do is that

1. according to the order they will be numered from 1 to N.
2. I want to sort them by number but according to they part number, so each part number will have a different order.

After that, they will be displayed with it entry date and ordered and then I will know which one has to be the first removed.

When I remove one, the next will be number 1 and all of them will be reordered.

My code is below:

```
class Box
{
public string partNumber;
public int fifo;
public DateTime date;
public int quantity;
public int position;
public int orderColumn;
public int boxnum;

public Caja(string partNumber, int fifo, int quantity, int position, DateTime date, int orderColumn, int boxnum)
{
    this.partNumber = partNumber;
    this.fifo = fifo;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.position = position;
    this.date = date;
    this.orderColumn = orderColumn;
    this.boxnum = boxnum;
 }
}
```

This is the method to order the objects, and its where I'm stuck:

```
class BoxCollection : List<box>
{

    public Color GetBoxColor(Box box)
    {
        return GetBoxColor(IndexOf(box));
    }

    public Color GetBoxColor(int index)
    {

        var firstBox = this.OrderBy(c => c.date)
            .First(c => c.partNumber == this[index].partNumber);

        return index == IndexOf(firstBox) ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
    }
    public  int GetBoxFifo(Box box)
    {
        return GetBoxFifo(IndexOf(box));
    }
    public int GetBoxFifi(int index)
    {
        var firstBox = this.OrderBy(c => c.date)
             .First(c => c.partNumber == this[index].partNumber);
        return index == IndexOf(firstBox);
    }
}
```

I use this method to sort them

```
foreach(var p in objCajaCollection.OrderBy(c => c.fecha))
{
        p.fifo = i;
       i++;
}
```

SO MY PROBLEM IS that I don't know how to make the method to ALSO separate them by part number.
The expected output is that it show multiple lists and each one has to be sorted according to date, but each list with its own order.

**My idea is that you have the boxes ordered by date but, each part number has to have its own order, so if I take off a box of the X part number, the order of the Y part number doesn't change at all.**

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: ...or problem or error.  Stuck how? where?

Comment: why not use the extension method: `foo.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)`

Comment: It might help us understand if you gave us an example list before and after the sort process and the expected output.

Comment: [The answer is in the next question, thank you all](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137278/mejorar-metodo-para-que-regrese-un-valor-de-prioriadad-dentro-de-una-lista)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class Box
    {
        public string partNumber;
        public DateTime date;
        public int quantity;
        public int position;
        public int orderColumn;
        public int boxnum;

        public Box(string partNumber, int quantity, int position, DateTime date, int orderColumn, int boxnum)
        {
            this.partNumber = partNumber;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.position = position;
            this.fecha = date;
            this.orderColumn = orderColumn;
            this.boxnum = boxnum;
        }
    }

        class BoxCollection : List<Box>
    {

        public Color GetBoxColor(Box box)
        {
        return GetBoxColor(IndexOf(box));
    }

    public Color GetBoxColor(int index)
    {
        return GetBoxFifo(index) == 1 ? Color.Red : Color.Green;
    }

    public int GetBoxFifo(Box box)
    {
        return GetBoxFifo(IndexOf(box));
    }

    public int GetBoxFifo(int index)
    {
        return this.Where(c => c.partNumber == this[index].partNumber)
            .OrderBy(c=> c.date).ToList().IndexOf(this[index]) + 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

(If you are trying to find index and then the original index is not supported -)

When I found a way to sort a ListView on click on the internet, I then added a Column that holds the original list item number (but just to help identify the item in the original list elsewhere).

[Image of part of a ListView showing indexes as strings. (The ColumnHeaders are actually clickable.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnQlK.png)